# Why do I get a syntax error when using CAST in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL workbench v5.2.44 CE. I am running it against a local MySQL 5.5 install.

I am trying to use the `CAST` function, but keep getting the following error:

> syntax error, unexpected INT_SYM

It doesn't matter what the source and target date types are. The only time it doesn't give me an error is when the target datatype is `DECIMAL`. Here is an example:

```
SELECT CAST(IFNULL(comboCount, 1) * COUNT(partID) AS INT) INTO comboCount
FROM productOption
```

I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: @BobDuell `INT` is not a valid type for `CAST`

Comment: Replace `INT` with either `SIGNED`, `UNSIGNED` or `DECIMAL(20)` (to have `comboCount` interpreted as an integer value.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to do the math outside:

```
SELECT CAST(IFNULL(comboCount, 1) AS INT) * COUNT(partID) INTO comboCount
FROM productOption
```

If that doesn't work, try to `CAST` as `UNSIGNED`; not `INT`.

Comment: Thanks njk. so doing the math outside doesn't work. unsigned works. but I dont understand why. what if I want to cast it as FLOAT . FLOAT gives me the same error.

Comment: @SilentUser The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) specifies available types. You need to use `decimal`

Comment: @njk I'm confused; is the answer as written correct or should it be `AS DECIMAL`?

Comment: The answer is correct with `UNSIGNED`. OP also had another instance when using a decimal.

Comment: You could use either `SIGNED`, `UNSIGNED` or `DECIMAL(20)`.  The syntax given in the answer will throw an error,  because it has the same problem as the original query... the bare `INT` keyword is not valid as a type for CAST.

Comment: @spencer7593 be louder mate, you saved my day. DECIMAL requires range to be specified. So if you give it a safe range. It's doing things as you expect it to do.