# Cast string to INT mysql

Tags: mysql, casting

I have unix format date (1414326637) this would be a human readable(2014-10-26 13:30:37).

All that I want is take a part of a human readable date(SUBSTRING(FROM_UNIXTIME(time),11,3)) and take just hours part.

I need filter by hours eg(07:00:00 - 14:59:59) but I cant.

I think this would be with CAST function, but I don't know. I'm trying this and i getting error on INT:

```
SELECT *,FROM_UNIXTIME(time),CAST(SUBSTRING(FROM_UNIXTIME(time),11,3) AS INT ) as Hours
FROM aulavirtual.mdl_log where action = "view" 
and Hours BETWEEN 07 AND 14 order by userid,time
```

**error message**

> Syntax error, unexpected INT_SYM

Can anyone help ?

Comment: its traditional to print the error message

Comment: Thats the error message: Syntax error, unexpected INT_SYM

Comment: check this post [why-do-i-get-a-syntax-error-when-using-cast-in-mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531087/why-do-i-get-a-syntax-error-when-using-cast-in-mysql)

Comment: That's why you have computer formats (like Unix timestamps) to handle dates in the first place: doing any kind of calculation with plain text is a pain in the ass; don't do it if it's not too late.

Comment: This post helps a lot!!

My problem was i had not UNSIGNED INTEGER.

My final query is:
SELECT *,FROM_UNIXTIME(time)
 FROM aulavirtual.mdl_log 
where action = "view" 
  AND CAST(SUBSTRING(FROM_UNIXTIME(time),11,3) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) >= 07 
  AND CAST(SUBSTRING(FROM_UNIXTIME(time),11,3) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) <=14
order by (time)

And it works because i put in: CAST(SUBSTRING(FROM_UNIXTIME(time),11,3) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)

Thanks guys!

Comment: My eyes!!! Please check PerroVerd's answer for a sensible solution.

Comment: It's too late because is a Moodle's database , I would not have done so

Comment: I'm not talking about changing your database design, I'm talking about the query you're currently tweaking. I assume you can write it however you want :-?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something easier try the HOUR function

```
SELECT *, HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) as Hours
FROM aulavirtual.mdl_log where action = "view" 
and HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) BETWEEN 07 AND 14 order by userid,time
```

Comment: I get Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Hours' in 'where clause'

Seems more easy if it worked

Comment: You have to write the full `HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(time))` expression in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Edited, yep its like Alvaro said. Also notice that mdl_log usually grows big and the HOUR function over the substring, cast its a lot faster

Comment: Now it works!! Too much simpler than the other one.

Really thanks!